# Does the file handling projects are good for Openshift migration?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, containers, cloud, openshift

Does the file handling projects are good for OpenShift migration?

Our project is file driven and data driven project which is mostly Python and Perl programs runs through the cron or Autosys mostly.

Since am new to cloud am asking this question. Out of hundreds of batches i will give few example.

1. Perl or Python program which reads the hundreds of files and insert the data into the DB.
2. Python or Perl program which reads the data from the DB and writes that to the file.
3. Consolidating the hundreds of files to the single file.
4. Sending the response to the solace queue based on the data from the file.

Please suggest these scenarios of projects are good for OpenShift migration.

Comment: Anything whose primary mode of operation is "reading and writing files" won't be a good match for a container-based or cluster-oriented environment.  If you can reorient this approach towards operating on the database records or some sort of batch-processing system it could work.  It's hard to come up with a concrete answer based on just what you've suggested as an outline.

Comment: So you mean if any action of program which involves the file handling is not suggested for container environment...?

Comment: If a core part of your workflow is "process A writes files into some directory, then process B reads those same files back" – if there's ever a point that depends on multiple processes being in the same filesystem – there will be operational trouble running it in containers.  If "process A uploads data somewhere, then process B downloads that same data" it works better (where "somewhere" could be a database, network storage like AWS S3, ...).